# To pass the ID of DIV tag in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am learning JQuery.

```
<Div ID="top">
<DIV ID="testing1">
<DIV ID="testing2"><DIV ID="testing3">...<DIV ID="testing100"></Div>
```

Since there are tens of DIV tags with different ID generated by a PHP file
And I am trying to pass a dynamic ID of a DIV tag to a JQuery self-defined function:

```
<script>$(function() {
 $("div").mouseover(function() {
      var ID = $(this).children().attr('id');
      alert(ID);     });}); </script>
```

But it wont work.

Comment: Just a note: your HTML code is not valid. DIVs always need a closing tag, even if they have no content: <div id="foo"></div>

Comment: You have a roundabout way of attaching this function. Change the function to receive an element instead of its ID, or make the function work on `$(this)` element. Then you can simply bind it using `$("div").mouseover(myFunction);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example works, and event bubbling results in three calls, each in turn giving an id of "testing2", "testing1" and then "top" in that order.

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="testing1">
        <div id="testing2">x</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("div").mouseover(function () {
        var ID = this.id;
        alert(ID);     
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ID of the DIV that triggered the event, you can just use `$(this).id()` instead of the `$(this).children().attr("id")`.

children() would give you an array of all elements that are inside your DIV. But getting one ID from a list of multiple elements will be kind of problematic ;)

if you want the ID of the first element inside your DIV, try `$(this).children().first().id()`.

Comment: You can use `this.id` inside the event handler. No need to wrap in jquery, since jquery takes care of it being in context.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.children()` - you want the id attribute of the `div`, so you don't need to go to its children for that.

Also, you can use `.id()` instead of `.attr('id')`.

Thus, it becomes simply `$(this).id()` to get the id of the element on which the function was invoked.

Answer (score 1):

To run through multiple IDs of f.e. listings you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a[voteid]').click (function(){
var nid = $(this).attr("voteid");
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "vote.php",
data: "name="+ nid,
dataType: "html",
success:function(data){ $("span#voteajax" + nid).html(data)},
error:function(xhr,err,e){ alert( "Error: " + err ); }
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

The HTML in the PHP page will be something like this:

```
<span id="voteajax<? echo $nid;?>"><a class="vbutton" voteid="<? echo $nid;?>" title="Vote!"><? echo $listings['votes'];?></a></span>
```

Hope this helps!

cheers,
John V